# The $k$th moments of normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, moments

How to proof that the $k$th moments of random variable $X\backsim N(0, \sigma^2)$ which is:

$$
E(X^k) = 
\begin{cases}
\sigma^k(k!!) & \text{for k even;}\\
\
0 & \text{for k odd}
\end{cases}
$$

I started from the basic definition of the $k$th moments:

$$E(X^k) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{- \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$

What kind of integration techniques that could solve this equation?

Comment: The result that you are trying to prove is false except when $\mu=0$.

Comment: Have you heard of [the moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function)?